# Getting highcharts to re-animate a line graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, highcharts

I would like to create a highCharts page with a button to "re-animate" the chart.

When I initially create the series, I set the 'redraw' to FALSE:

```
   $("contain").highcharts().addSeries({                        
        name: "filter",
        data: result
   }, false, {duration: 300000, easing: 'linear'});
```

When I then manually call redraw() on the entire chart:

```
$("contain").highcharts().redraw()
```

...the chart animates from the start - *BUT ONLY ONCE*. After the charts are animated 'on-screen', I've found no way to have them re-animate from the start **EXCEPT FOR REMOVING AND THEN RE-ADDING, not an ideal solution for my case as there will be many series (lines) & ALOT of data such that I was hoping there was a simpler solution** (*I see somebody answered while I editted the question*)...

Is there any way to do this or will have to remove and then re-add the series each time I want to re-animate?

Here is the fiddle I promised earlier. It's using the remove/re-add concept which I do not love : http://jsfiddle.net/bhilleli/854jbbhg/

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: I will have to refactor it out of a larger system to put it online which is the only reason I didn't put one up earlier (lots of dependencies/hooks)... Will do this ASAP; just ran out of time... I don't understand why this was downvoted (1st time for everything?!) -- this is a specific question for a specific problem.

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli , are you using $.getJSON(endpoint,params,function(){})? That is how I refresh my charts.

Comment: No, but if that worked I could easily adapt to using it. Question: if you .getJSON a series (1 'line' in a line graph); and then getJSON the very same series (same data etc), is the entire graph redrawn and re-animated? If so, have you any examples? I've added a fiddle that achieves the goal using removing/readding - but am hoping for a more elegant solutions...'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reanimate the same series, you will want to remove your current one and redraw it as a new series.

```
 $('#button').click(function() {
    $("contain").highcharts().series[0].remove();
    $("contain").highcharts().addSeries({
       name:"filter",
       data: result} );

});
```

Comment: Thanks. While you were answering I was clarifying the question. I was hoping to do this WITHOUT having to remove and re-add the series (see editting question above); I am wondering if thats possible.

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli , I believe the other way is to use `$("contain").highcharts().series[0].setData(data,true);`, this calls the `redraw()` method. But it stills consists of readding the series, just not removing.

Comment: If the line is already on the screen when this is called it will not be redrawn OR perhaps it is redrawn, but because it doesn't first 'clear' it would be writing a blue line over an identical blue line (effectively the screen stays the same, no reanimation). Thx though